# Many items in `IN` clause causing full table scan earlier than expected

Tags: query-performance, mysql-8.0

We have a search index table, provided by a CMS, that is of the form:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `craft_searchindex` (
  `elementId` int NOT NULL,
  `attribute` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fieldId` int NOT NULL,
  `locale` char(12) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`elementId`,`attribute`,`fieldId`,`locale`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `craft_searchindex_keywords_idx` (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci
```

As part of the search functionality provided by the CMS, the following query is formed:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `craft_searchindex` WHERE (`keywords` LIKE '% tom %') AND `locale` = 'en_au' AND `elementId` IN (<ids>)
```

where `ids` is a filtered list of `elementId`s based on a previous query.

What we have observed is that when we reach a certain number of items in that `IN` clause, the performance drops off and query execution time becomes constant, as shown from a graph collected before migration to InnoDB (y-axis execution time in milliseconds, x-axis number of items in `IN` clause, series min/mean/max):

[image]

The last line of an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query shows the following for ~33500 items:

```
-> Index range scan on craft_searchindex using PRIMARY over (elementId = 1) OR (elementId = 128) OR (33500 more)  (cost=55355 rows=234514) (actual time=0.0376..537 rows=469028 loops=1)
```

and for ~34000 items:

```
-> Table scan on craft_searchindex  (cost=335885 rows=3.27e+6) (actual time=0.0303..3237 rows=3.72e+6 loops=1)
```

My interpretation of this (which comports with the graph) is that:

- up to some threshold the primary key index is scanned (one-by-one, providing the linear growth), and
- beyond that threshold the full table is always scanned (providing the constant value)

My question is, given that there is significant difference between the execution time immediately below this threshold and the time above it, why does the query planner choose to abandon scanning the index[*], and can anything be done about it (with the constraint that the query preparation is performed by the CMS, so mostly out of our hands)?

### Joining on a temporary table

While not a solution for us given the constraints of the queries being handled by the CMS, I've pursued @Akina's suggestion of using an indexed temporary table. This changes the query from (effectively):

```sql
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1 << 19;
PREPARE ids_stmt FROM 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)
INTO @ids_clause
FROM (
  SELECT `elements`.`id`
  FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
  JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
  JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id
  JOIN `craft_users` `users` ON users.id = elements.id
  WHERE ((elements_i18n.locale = ?) AND (content.locale = ?)) AND (elements.archived = 0)
) AS `ids`';
SET @l = 'en_au';
EXECUTE ids_stmt USING @l, @l;  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ids_stmt;

SET @search_query = CONCAT("SELECT `craft_searchindex`.* FROM `craft_searchindex` WHERE (`keywords` LIKE '% tom %') AND `locale` = 'en_au' AND `elementId` IN (", @ids_clause, ')');

PREPARE search_stmt FROM @search_query;
EXECUTE search_stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE search_stmt;
```

to:

```sql
PREPARE ids_stmt FROM 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids_table
(PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
SELECT `elements`.`id`
FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id
JOIN `craft_users` `users` ON users.id = elements.id
WHERE ((elements_i18n.locale = ?) AND (content.locale = ?)) AND (elements.archived = 0)
LIMIT 1';
SET @l = 'en_au';
EXECUTE ids_stmt USING @l, @l; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ids_stmt;

SELECT `craft_searchindex`.*
FROM `craft_searchindex`
JOIN `ids_table` ON `craft_searchindex`.`elementId` = `ids_table`.`id`
WHERE (`keywords` LIKE '% tom %') AND `locale` = 'en_au';
```

and this maintains the linear execution time growth well beyond the previous threshold.

Interestingly (and perhaps because the temporary table has only one column) dropping the primary key has no effect on the execution time.

Below is a graph comparing these (times are now in seconds):
[image]

[*]: From some brief back of the envelope calculations, continuing to scan the index instead of performing a full table scan would still be below the full table scan execution time until the number of items in the `IN` clause exceeded ~200,000

Comment: *where ids is a filtered list of elementIds based on a previous query* Save them into indexed temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The actual culprit

When exploring the suggestion from @Akina, I noticed that there was a warning output from the SQL execution which I hadn't noticed before. This warning spells it all out:

```
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 3170 | Memory capacity of 8388608 bytes for 'range_optimizer_max_mem_size' exceeded. Range optimization was not done for this query. |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is something that we *can* address, as we can both modify the parameter on the DB instance (long term) and modify this per session via use of some initial SQL statements run at connection time (short term). And so, adding:

```sql
SET SESSION range_optimizer_max_mem_size = 1 << 24;
```

to the (effective) original query above gives the following, much rosier, performance graph:

[image]